# Why introduce very ample sheaf and ample sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

I'm reading Hartshorne recently. He introduces the concepts 'very ample' and 'ample' sheaf. I could understand the definitions of them. But I have no idea why they are important.

1.Is there any geometric meaning of (very) ample? How to understand these concepts?

2.Also, when we define very ample, we use the concept 'immersion' which seems not really well-behaved. Why we use embedding rather than other better conditions, for example, closed/open immersion.

Comment: Why is an immersion in to projective space not "geometric" enough for you in your first question? And immersions (once you fix Hartshorne's definition!) are actually pretty well behaved. What don't you like about them?

Comment: It seems that the composition of immersions is not immersion(not sure). And I'm not sure why we care about an open embedding followed by a closed embedding.

Comment: Could I regard very ample sheaf as some sort of restriction of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$ on its subscheme?

Comment: You're right that as stated in Hartshorne, the composition of immersions need not be an immersion. But there are ways to fix this - either requiring that the target be locally noetherian, which fits well with Hartshorne's philosophy regarding noetherian assumptions, or by changing the order of open/closed so that it matches the definition as in EGA and elsewhere. But these are mere technical points - immersions are very geometric! If you think you don't care about them, can you explain what geometric means to you? And your second comment is literally the definition of a very ample sheaf.

Comment: @KReiser Is there also any geometric or intuitive way to understand 'ample sheaf'?

Comment: This one's a little harder for me to give a good response to (I would not say I have a good geometric intuition), but here goes. Basically, something's ample but not very ample if it needs "a little more twisting" in order to get enough sections to define an immersion. The easiest example to get your hands on would be a line bundle of degree 2 on an elliptic curve - this (generically) doesn't have sections, but it's square does.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for your explanation. It also seems that ample sheaf will play a role just like O(1) or O(m) for projective space. The definition of Hilbert polynomial depends on a given ample sheaf.